# Can Arden's theorem provide multiple regular expressions for a given DFA if the order and process of solving the equations are changed?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, dfa

I was using Arden's theorem for the conversion of DFA to regular expressions and noticed that it is providing different regular expressions if the method and order of solving the equations are changed.

Is it supposed to give a unique solution and its a mistake from my side or can it actually provide multiple regular expressions for "a given DFA"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.